# QGIS - Select by expression - howto make multiple selections/querys

Tags: python, sql, gis, qgis

I have an attribute table with ~ 100 fields and I want to select some fields. So far my workflow looks like this:

```
Select by expression 
   "field1"
Add to selection

Select by expression 
   "field2"
Add to selection

Select by expression 
   "field3"
Add to selection

Select by expression 
   "field4"
Add to selection
```

... and so on ...

Now my Question is how to make the selection faster and combine more then 1 query. I know a little python, but don't know how to use the Function Editor. A little script and how to handle it in the Function Editor would be the thing i am looking for, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Say your DB has two columns named `fruit` and `place` and you've to select rows where `fruit` is `apple` or `place` is `india`.

Use the following

```
"fruit" = 'apple' OR "place" = 'india'
```

Comment: then i am getting all the apples with the place in india. Maybe i was not clear enough. I edited my starting post, to be more specific

Comment: Do you want all to be added in a single selection?

Comment: Use OR then. I've edited the answer, see if it works for you.

Comment: tried that already ... unfortunately it is selecting nothing when using the OR-Operator

Comment: Hmm figured out that it works when I search for attributes in a field. But not when I want to select multiple field, where it's only selecting the not 'NULL' features.